# Using boost asio tcp in visual studio 2017 with CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017, boost-asio

I'm trying to include and use boost ASIO TCP in a simple project in visual studio 2017 with CMake, but I receive this error when I run the project:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib'
```

These are steps to prepare the project:

1. Update VS 2017 to last version (15.7.2)
2. Download boost 1.67.0
3. In VS Command Prompt run Bootstrap, and b2.exe
4. Define Boost_ROOT in environment variables
5. Create a CMake project in VS

Then this is my CMakeList.text:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (TcpSample)
set(EXEC_NAME "TcpSample")
add_executable (${EXEC_NAME} "TcpSample.cpp" "TcpSample.h")

SET(BOOST_MANDATORY_COMPONENTS system date_time)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost "1.67.0" COMPONENTS ${BOOST_MANDATORY_COMPONENTS} 
REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

And finally the code:

```
#include "TcpSample.h"
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to mention that if I change tcp to udp, there is no error.

Comment: It is attempting to link to the 32 bit version of `boost::date_time`. Did you build the `boost` libraries as 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: You need either add `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` to fulfill all your requested Boost components or add `${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY}` to your `target_link_libraries` command. I would also recommend to use `target_include_directories(${EXEC_NAME} 
 ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` instead of plain `include_directories` command.

Comment: @kenba I'm not sure which. My OS is windows 10 64 bit, and I just used simple Bootstrap and b2.exe without any argument in VS command prompt.

Comment: @vre It worked by adding ${Boost_LIBRARIES} or ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY} to target_link_libraries. Thanks! 
Although, the target_include_directories(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) raises an error which says it is called with invalid arguments!

Comment: My fault. You should use `target_include_directories(${EXEC_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` instead. See the CMake help for further explanations on the command.

Comment: @vre Your comments answered my question. Would you post it so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments to an answer:

You are missing to link your executable to the `date_time` library of Boost. Including a different header might remove this link dependency as you noticed.

Most Boost libraries are header only. But some are not and require adding the library to the `target_link_libraries` command. This can be done once for all libraries found by command `find_package(Boost "1.67.0" COMPONENTS system date_time REQUIRED)` by adding

```
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

or adding single libraries as follows

```
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY})
```

And while you are at it turn the command `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` that adds the Boost include directories to all targets in the `CMakeLists.txt` into a target specific `target_include_directories(${EXEC_NAME} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. If you need to link `PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE` depends on whether your library/DLL/shared object exposes types from the Boost libraries.